# Setting user-defined cookies in Jmeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter

There doesn't seem to be much information around on forcing Cookie values in JMeter (2.8).

I'd like to be able to set a cookie at the start of a thread (AWS LoadBalancer ID), so that i can select a specific ID each time. The reason for this is that AWS gives the same ELB ID every time unless you change IP. I want to test more than one.

I have tried setting user-defined cookies in the HTTP Cookie Manager without success. (nothing is added)

I have also tried adding a COOKIE_Test to HTTP Header Manager without success. (adds to the header but doesn't treat as cookie)

Might not be possible?

**Update**: Adding the domain entry fixed it...
On inspecting the normal set-cookie, it omitted the domain, so i did the same...
I guess Cookie Manager ignores and user-defined cookies with null values.

Comment: Sounds like you put your _Update_ in an answer. Or, if you think the issue is too trivial, even delete the question.

Comment: You shoud answer your own question and accept it so that it helps others

Comment: @stickx Yeah, in jmeter 2.11 and 2.13, for me, when i add a cookie in the User Defined Cookies panel, and hit "Save", it tries to save to an external file called cookies.txt instead of just saving it to jmeter .jmx project file.  Wierd.!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the domain entry fixed it

On inspecting the normal set-cookie, it omitted the domain, so i did the same...

Cookie Manager ignores any user-defined cookies with null values.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the Cookie Manager User Interface?

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

Comment: Quote: "I have tried setting user-defined cookies in the HTTP Cookie Manager without success. (nothing is added)"

Comment: It is possible, I have used it in the past, not able to see what is not working for you. any errors, exceptions, in the log?

Comment: Adding the domain entry fixed it...
On inspecting the normal set-cookie, it omitted the domain, so i did the same...
I guess Cookie Manager ignores and user-defined cookies with null values.